# How to find indexOf element in jQuery array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexof

I have two selectors

```
    var allNodes = $("a.historyEntry");
    var errorNodes = $("a.historyEntry.error");
```

I would like to to find a node before first error node, so I need to find an index of first error node, how to do it?

I tried to use inArray method, but it doesn't work for this

```
$.inArray(allNodes, errorNodes.first())
```

or

```
$.inArray(allNodes, $(errorNodes.first()))
```

Is there any fast way to do it in jQuery or do I have to use for loop?

Comment: If I understand you correctly: some of the nodes in `allNodes` have the `error` class, and you want to find the last "good" node before the first "error" node. Is that right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)?

It's like `indexOf`... but just without the `Of`... it returns the index of the element if it exists, and -1 if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/). It does exactly the same thing as `indexOf` in java.

Answer (score 2):

[**$.inArray**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) value is the first parameter then the array:

```
$.inArray(allNodes, errorNodes.first())
```

should be:

```
$.inArray(errorNodes.first(), allNodes)
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jjwpq/)